# sudo apt-get upgrade returns an error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and every time I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get this error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: tar subprocess returned error exit status 1 

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):

dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In addition to this, when I try to install any `.deb` file with `sudo apt install`. I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Sub-process Popen returned an error code (2)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /home/paras/Downloads/code_1.37.1-1565886362_amd64.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Please help.

Answer (score -2):

You could try clearing the apt cache with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Update the package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Fix any incomplete installations

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And finally

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am not sure if this is exactly what you need to solve your problem but you can give it a try.

Comment: Please don't post answers if you are "not sure"; you could be doing more harm than good.

Comment: Gave the same error. :(